# Affine Cipher in C doesn't work correctly

Tags: c, error-handling, cryptography

***Disclaimer: Whatever is below, it's related to Affine Cipher. For whomever doesn't know it, it's a encrypting method that uses a mathematical function Ax+B to shift each letter in a given plaintext according to the letter's index in the alphabet.***

I've written a code that encrypts and decrypts a given plaintext or ciphered text using Affine Cipher. It consists of these three functions:

```
char *encryption(char Plaintext[MAXSIZE], int A, int B);
int modularinverse(int number, int modulo);
char *decryption(char Ciphered[MAXSIZE], int A, int B, int inverse);
```

The part that concerns me sites in the decryption function. Around three or four letters are miss-calculated.

Let's consider the following plaintext: "a b c d e"

Using the encryption function:

```
char *encryption(char Plaintext[MAXSIZE], int A, int B) {
    static char Ciphered[MAXSIZE];
    int i;
    int y;
    int index;
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(Plaintext) - 1; i++) {
        if (Plaintext[i] == ' ') {
            Ciphered[i] = ' ';
        } else {
            index = (int)Plaintext[i] - 'a';
            y = (A * index + B) % 26;
            Ciphered[i] = (char)y + 97;
        }
    }
    return Ciphered;
}
```

it turns the plaintext into: "f m t a h". Which is correct.

Decrypting the plaintext should obviously give: "a b c d e". But instead, it gives: "a b c J e".

```
char *decryption(char Ciphered[MAXSIZE], int A, int B, int inverse) {
    static char NewPlaintext[MAXSIZE];
    int i;
    unsigned int x;
    int y;
    int index;
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(Ciphered); i++) {
        if (Ciphered[i] == ' ') {
            NewPlaintext[i] = ' ';
        } else {
            index = (int)Ciphered[i] - 'a';
            x = inverse * (index - B) % 26;
            NewPlaintext[i] = (char)x + 97;
        }
    }
    return NewPlaintext;
}
```

The letter `d` is miss-calculated for a reason I don't know. Printing the values of variables `index`, `inverse`, `B` and `x` for each one of the characters `f m t a h` will respectively return this:

```
5         15        5         0
12        15        5         1
19        15        5         2
0         15        5         -23
7         15        5         4
```

First column represents indexes of the letters `f m t a h`.

Second column represents the inverse of `A=7`, which is `15`. (Totally harmful, you may ignore it).

Third column represents B which is a constant for now (You may ignore it).

Fourth column represents x which is the result of `inverse*(index-B) % 26`. Adding 97 (ASCII number of 'a') to each of number in this column will result to the ASCII number of each letter.

i.e 0+97 = 97 which is 'a'. By consequence Decryption(f)=a.

But if you can notice. the result of x for the letter 'a' is -23. -23+97=74 which is J in ASCII. It should rather be 100 as it's the ASCII number for d. Therefore the result of x should rather be 3, not -23.

**The reason behind this miss-calculation is buzzing me and I haven't figured out what's causing it.**

Comment: I assume you are doing this to learn coding. If so work on the problem yourself, learning how to debug is very important. Add print statements, trace execution, add breakpoints, watch variables and **think**. [Richard Feynman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Feynman) fixed radios by thinking. Think: "How could this happen"?

Comment: @zaph I've tried, but I can't figure out why the compiler thinks the result of a simple calculation is -23. I've tested it by hand it gives me 3 as it should be.

Comment: @Amine: the compiler does not *think*, it generates code and the expression you wrote can have a negative value if `B` is greater than `index`.  Division truncates toward `0`, and `-23 % 26` evaluates to `-23`.

Comment: @chqrlie but index-B is multiplied by inverse. It should be(in the case of decrypting a) 15*0-15-5%26 which is 3. It you google -75%26 it will yield 3

Comment: @Amine: In C, `-75%26` evaluates as `-(75%26)` which is definitely `-23`. `(-75)%26` evaluates to `-3`. Google search is not an interactive C compiler.  Multiplying by `inverse` only works for `1` and `-1`, all other values of `A` are not supported with integer arithmetic.

Comment: @chqrlie What would you suggest to solve this? I've tried using `abs()` before but it didn't work, it rather returns x this time

Comment: @Amine: using `abs()` is incorrect, I wrote the solution in my answer: `x = ((inverse * (index - B) % 26) + 26) % 26;`

Comment: @chqrlie Thanks, it works.

Comment: Use `unsigned char`, that will eliminate the negative foolishness, foolishness because characters are not signed values.

Comment: @zaph: No, `unsigned char` will not make a difference. As a matter of fact, `char` may be signed or unsigned depending on the platform and compiler settings. Subtracting a character number from a value will yield a negative number if the value is smaller than 25.

Comment: @Amine: can you upvote my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has few issues which are causing this strange behavior;

1. Don't use `int` type if you are dealing with character. Use `char`
2. In `decryption()` handle if the value of `x` is negative.

you can modify your `decryption()` like this.

```
char *decryption(char Ciphered[MAXSIZE],int A, int B, int inverse)
{
    static char NewPlaintext[MAXSIZE];
    char x;
    char index;
    for(int i=0;i<strlen(Ciphered);i++)
    {
        if(Ciphered[i]==' ')
        {
            NewPlaintext[i]=' ';
        }
        else
        {
            index=(int)Ciphered[i] - 'a';
            x=inverse*(index-B) % 26;
            if(x < 0)
            {
                // add 26 to take care of negative values; since you are using %
                x += 26;
            }
            NewPlaintext[i]=(char)x+97;
        }
    }
    return NewPlaintext;
}
```

I tested it few entries and it works fine.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Amine you need to modify your encryption() method also. Use char instead of int.

Comment: char instead of int where? I already defined the function type as char and it returns a char

Comment: use `unsigned char` instead of `char` then there are no signed values.

Comment: @Amine instead of int y and int index, you use char y and char index.

Comment: @SudiptaKumarSahoo you are, in the long run, not helping by providing an code. Sure it may help immediately with the hoe work but homework it there to make students figure out things.

Comment: @zaph in decryption() unsigned char won't work for negative values.

Comment: @SudiptaKumarSahoo Right, the reason I used int because I'm implementing a methematical function. I already made it clear that y and index will the take the integer value of the characters in the array `index=(int)Plaintext[i] - 'a';` and then the new array will take the character corresponding the integer values `Ciphered[i]=(char)y+'a';`

Answer (score 1):

Your code has several problems:

- you stop before the end of the string: `i<strlen(Plaintext)-1`
- you do not null terminate the destination strings.
- your return a pointer to static storage: only one string can be encrypted/decyphered at a time.
- depending on the values, you may take the modulo of negative numbers, which will be negative too.  Use this instead: `x = ((inverse * (index - B) % 26) + 26) % 26;`

Comment: I stop before the size of the string because its size is 1024 as it's definedi n MAXSIZE. Both functions will count the end of the string \0

I don't understand the second one and you should explain more in the third one

Comment: @Amine: `strlen(Plaintext)` counts the number of characters in `Plaintext` before the `'\0'`, which is different from `sizeof(Plaintext)`, which in your case would be the size of a `char*`, not the size of the array passed as an argument.  Defining `char *encryption(char Plaintext[MAXSIZE], int A, int B)` is exactly equivalent to `char *encryption(char *Plaintext, int A, int B)`

Comment: I've tested without using the -1. the encryption function will also encrypt the empty space. "Donner votre mot/phrase: a
Donner A et B: 7 5
f[" this is compiled without substracting -1 from the strlen

Comment: @Amine: probably because it encrypts the `'\n'`.  Use `if (isspace(PlainText[i])) { Ciphered[i] = PlainText[i]; } else...`